# How to get One Signal unique user id in Mobile?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, onesignal, unique-id

I am developing a restaurant app. I am using One Signal in my app to send notifications. Here while I place the order I need to send the unique Id of the one signal for a specific user for getting notification of "Your Order is placed successfully... It is in Progress.Please wait". For that I need the user's One Signal user id. How can I get it? I am newbie to One Signal. Please help me.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Got the unique Id of OneSignal  by using the following code which is in official site of OneSignal.**

```
OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
        @Override
        public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
            Log.d("debug", "User:" + userId);
            if (registrationId != null)
                Log.d("debug", "registrationId:" + registrationId);

        }
    });
```

Refer:

[Getting code in Official Site](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-api#IdsAvailableHandler)

This Above Code is Deprecated. Please use the below code.

```
String UUID = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId()
```

Comment: I was trying to do this on iOS and this explains how to do it. Its the same logic in iOS

Comment: Sorry ..no idea for IOS ji @blackmoon

Comment: Any solution for iOS @blackmon

Comment: The above solution for android is deprecated 
Use:

    OSPermissionSubscriptionState status = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
    status.getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();

Comment: String UUID = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId()

its returning null! :(

Comment: Does not work for their latest release 4.0.0. :(

Comment: @ParamaSudha What method we can use to get UserID from OneSignal in WebView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript

Answer (score 17):

The above solution for android is deprecated 
Use:

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState status = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
status.getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();
```

Comment: A one liner: `OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId()`

Comment: String UUID = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId() 
its returning null! :(

Comment: Does not work for their latest release 4.0.0. :(

Answer (score 14):

**Android Java**

```
String userId = OneSignal.getDeviceState().getUserId();
```

**Android Kotlin**

```
val oneSignalUserID = OneSignal.getDeviceState()!!.userId
```

**iOS OneSignal Version 3.6.0**

```
guard let userID = OneSignal.getDeviceState().userId else { return }
```

**iOS Old OneSignal Version**

```
let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
    if let id = status.subscriptionStatus.userId {
    oneSignalPlayer_ID = id
    print("\nOneSignal UserId:", id)
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Other solutions (including the accepted one) might be deprecated. They didn't work on Android Studio/Java.

Comment: What method we can use to get the use id from onesignal in web view app..? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript

Answer (score 4):

For android, you can get the userIDs aka playerIDs starting in the 3.5.0+ version of the native Android SDK using the getPermissionSubscriptionState method and addSubscriptionObserver.

For more on using getPermissionSubscriptionState see: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--getpermissionsubscriptionstate-

For adding subscription observers see: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--addsubscriptionobserver-

There is a Native Android example on Github:
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK

It is in the Examples folder labeled AndroidStudio

For iOS, you can get the playerIDs starting in the 2.5.0 version of the native iOS SDK using the getPermissionSubscriptionState method and addSubscriptionObserver.

For more on using getPermissionSubscriptionState see: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--getpermissionsubscriptionstate-

For adding subscription observers see: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--addsubscriptionobserver-

There is an iOS Example project in Swift on Github that might be of some assistance: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/Examples

Answer (score 3):

for **iOS**:

```
let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
    if let id = status.subscriptionStatus.userId {
    oneSignalPlayer_ID = id
    print("\nOneSignal UserId:", id)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the latest documentation,

Can get **Subscription-ID** or **Player-ID** as below,

```
OneSignal.getUser().getPushSubscription().getId()
```

Similarly, we can get the **token** as below,

```
OneSignal.getUser().getPushSubscription().getToken()
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution:

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        String UUID = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();
    }
}
```

Comment: this line returns null OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();

Comment: What method we can use to get UserID from OneSignal in WebView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

OneSignal 4.1 Android `String playerId = OneSignal.getDeviceState().getUserId();` to get player id

Comment: What method we can use to get UserID from OneSignal in WebView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 15 and as of OneSignal iOS SDK version 3.7.0

```
if let userId = OneSignal.getDeviceState().userId {
    print("OneSignal User ID: \(userId)")
}
```

Comment: What method we can use to get UserID from OneSignal in WebView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript

Comment: @HarishKolliparat damn I have no idea, this post has been 5 years old. A lot has changed.

Answer (score 1):

On OneSignal **v11.0** is `OneSignal.getDeviceState()` is deprecated.
To get userId use this

```
User.pushSubscription.id
```

And for token use this:

```
User.pushSubscription.token
```

For more follow this: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-sdk#subscription-id

Answer (score 0):

@Lakshmi Reddy

in iOS, you can do like below:

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState* status = [OneSignal getPermissionSubscriptionState];
    status.permissionStatus.hasPrompted
    status.permissionStatus.status
//                                                            <- OneSignal idsAvailable is deprecated.it's the alternative
    status.subscriptionStatus.subscribed
    status.subscriptionStatus.userSubscriptionSetting
    status.subscriptionStatus.userId
    status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken
NSLog(@"Push Token - %@",status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken);
NSLog(@"Push User ID - %@",status.subscriptionStatus.userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String UUID = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId()
```

This returns null unless the SubscriptionStatus is changed. Please follow the link below to know how you can get OneSignal userId from getSubscriptionStatus' JSONObject.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65107184/1906738

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OneSignal version 2.6.1 and above:

```
var userId = OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState().then((userObject) => userObject.subscriptionStatus.userId).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Application Class

```
public void onCreate() {
   ...
   OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
   OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);

   // Use One Signal User ID
   OneSignal.getDeviceState().getUserId()
   ...
```

}

Comment: What method we can use to get UserID from OneSignal in WebView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin use below code.

```
val oneSignalUserID = OneSignal.getDeviceState()!!.userId
```

Comment: @4b0 What method we can use to get UserID from OneSignal in WebView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get player id

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OSSubscriptionObserver {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(this);
  }
  
  public void onOSSubscriptionChanged(OSSubscriptionStateChanges stateChanges) {
    if (!stateChanges.getFrom().getSubscribed() &&
        stateChanges.getTo().getSubscribed()) {
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
             .setMessage("You've successfully subscribed to push notifications!")
             .show();
        // get player ID
        stateChanges.getTo().getUserId();
      }
   
      Log.i("Debug", "onOSSubscriptionChanged: " + stateChanges);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get the player id.

OneSignal Version - com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.7.4

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionObserver;
import com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionStateChanges;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class OneSignal_PlayerID extends Activity implement OSSubscriptionObserver {

private static String TAG = "OneSignal_PlayerID";
private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
    OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(this);

}

@Override
public void onOSSubscriptionChanged(OSSubscriptionStateChanges stateChanges) {
    if (stateChanges.getTo().isSubscribed()){
        String playerId = stateChanges.getTo().getUserId();
        if (playerId!=null){
            Log.i(TAG,"OneSignal Player ID : "+playerId);
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

All of the above did not work for me in android.
from the latest version, I got this solution.

```
var userId = OneSignal.getDeviceState().then((value) => {
  var deviceInfo= JSON.stringify(value);
  console.log(deviceInfo.userId)
})
```

for anyone like me can use the above code to get a unique UserId.